# setOnCloseRequest Java FXML

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx-8

Well, I'm using JavaFX FXML, there's less info than just JavaFX, so I can use MVC, but I'm having trouble with adding a Confirmation Dialog so if i press alt + f4 or exit button in the window, a little confirmation dialog will show.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540500/alert-box-for-when-user-attempts-to-close-application-using-setoncloserequest-in), putting a event on setOnCloseOperation, does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("close.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
        e.consume(); // stop the event to do something before quitting
        closeRequest(stage); // method used to show a confirmation dialog
    });

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private void closeRequest(Stage stage){

    String msg =
            "Sure to quit?";
    Alert alerta = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alerta.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    alerta.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    alerta.initOwner(stage);
    alerta.getDialogPane().setContentText(msg);
    alerta.getDialogPane().setHeaderText(null);
    alerta.showAndWait()
            .filter(response -> response == ButtonType.OK)
            .ifPresent(response -> { stage.close(); }); // then we need to call the close method for a stage, if the response is ok.

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

So in your main class, the one that loads the fxml resource, you need to use the method setOnCloseOperation.

Fisrt you need to consume the event so you stop the program to be finished.
Then we call a method to show a confirmation box, then we can call .close method to close the stage.