# JavaFX 8: Intercepting appication "exit"

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In order to verify that all changes made by the user have been saved I want to intercept the exiting/quitting of a JavaFX application.

Is there a common way-to-go to achieve this like overriding an event or is there more to it?

Comment: Question seems similar to: [Alert Box For When User Attempts to close application using setOnCloseRequest in JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540500/alert-box-for-when-user-attempts-to-close-application-using-setoncloserequest-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As they have already said, this is done by intercepting `WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST`. You can then stop the suspension by calling `event.consume()`.

This is an example of how to capture the event and display a confirmation dialog. Depending on the user's choice, you can take serialization actions if you wish.

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
    alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    alert.setHeaderText("Exit");
    alert.setContentText("Do you want to exit?");

    alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.NO);
    Optional<ButtonType> optional = alert.showAndWait();

    if(optional.isPresent() && optional.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        // save data

        return;
    }

    event.consume();
});
```

In order for the implementation to be complete, you need to implement a logic for clear exit from the application from control. For example, when choosing from the File menu -> Close. When capturing the event, you must run `WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST` to trick the exit logic.

```
closeMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
    Window window = menuBar.getScene().getWindow();
    window.fireEvent(new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I there anythign wrong with calling Plattform.exit() from the component?

Comment: @Hannes no, it's not wrong. But if you want to achieve the above behavior you need to manually call the function that will ask the user if he wants to continue before calling `Plattform.exit()`

Comment: What I did: I call in the WindowEvent handler and in the meun action the same method where I do the user propt and than call Plattform.exit();

Comment: @Hannes yes, there is no problem doing so. You just need to always get the edge to the context in which the method is defined. Just keep in mind that `Plattform.exit()` will stop the application process (and perhaps you do not want it, for example, if we are talking about a dialog where the user is entering some data).

Comment: Thanks again :-) I was only wondering if `Plattform.exit()` is as 'radical' als `System.exit()` or if it is okey to use it to propperly shut down and invoke all the methods in the life cycle of an JavaFX application.

Answer (score 0):

In the class Application there is the [stop method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop--) which you can override possibly.

Comment: I know that I could override the `stop` method but at this point and I cannot provide any confirmation dialog to the user - what ever happens, the application will be closed anyways.