# Why aren't my files being saved when I override Application's stop() method?

Tags: java, javafx, jfilechooser, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I'm creating an application using Javafx and want to save data once the application is closed. I overrode the stop() method to add the ability to save files once the close button is clicked. When I look into the files, though, they are empty. Does closing the application automatically wipe out all the information from my code therefor I will be saving nothing once the save method is called? If not, why are my text files empty after I attempt to populate them? Thanks.

```
@Override
    public void stop() {
        try {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File dir = null;
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                dir = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            }
            if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That directory does not exist.");
            }
            File file1 = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Titles.txt");
            FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(file1);  // saves titles
            BufferedWriter output1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
                output1.write(titles.get(i));
                output1.newLine();
            }
            output1.close();
            fw1.close();

            File file2 = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Formats.txt");
            FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(file2);  // saves formats
            BufferedWriter output2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);
            for (int i = 0; i < formats.size(); i++) {
                output2.write(formats.get(i));
                output2.newLine();
            }
            output2.close();
            fw2.close();

            File file3 = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\ListViewItems.txt");
            FileWriter fw3 = new FileWriter(file3);  // saves ListView items
            BufferedWriter output3 = new BufferedWriter(fw3);
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getItems().size(); i++) {
                output3.write(items.getItems().get(i));
                output3.newLine();
            }
            output3.close();
            fw3.close();


            File file4 = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Titles.txt");
            FileWriter fw4 = new FileWriter(file4);  // saves media items from Library Class
            BufferedWriter output4 = new BufferedWriter(fw4);
            for (int i = 0; i < lib.getItemList().size(); i++) {
                output4.write(lib.getItemList().get(i).toString());
                output4.newLine();
            }
            output4.close();
            fw4.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check out `stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {});` https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=javafx.stage.Stage&method=setOnCloseRequest

Comment: Don’t mix Swing with JavaFX.  JavaFX has its own [FileChooser class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html).

Comment: I see that you are using swing. Are you sure that this method is running?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627945/javafx-8-intercepting-appication-exit/47634518#47634518

Comment: Everything seems ok and should work fine, except the `lib` Collection isn't producing a valid `String` . Check it, may be it's not working. I checked with a random `String` and everything works fine.