# Dialogue in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to implement a dialogue alert when the user clicks the close button. With the option for yes they do want to leave and no they don't.

```
Button button = new Button("Exit");
    gridPane.add(button, 12, 12);
    button.setOnAction(e ->{
        primaryStage.close();

    });
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540500/alert-box-for-when-user-attempts-to-close-application-using-setoncloserequest-in

Answer (score 4):

Use the `onCloseRequest` event of the stage for closing the window using the `X` button of the window:

```
private static boolean confirmClose() {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setContentText("Do you really want to close the app?");
    return alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.CANCEL) == ButtonType.OK;
}
```

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    if (!confirmClose()) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

Note that this event is not triggered when closing the window programmatically. You need to request user confirmation yourself in such a case:

```
button.setOnAction(evt -> {
    if (confirmClose()) {
        primaryStage.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a pretty good article which explains et give some examples about [`Alert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html)

The one you need is a *[Confirmation-Dialog](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/#confirmation-dialog)* :

```
button.setOnAction(e -> 
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Exit Application");
    alert.setHeaderText("Exit of the App");
    alert.setContentText("Do you really want to exit ? ");

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
        primaryStage.close();
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Button button = new Button("Exit");
gridPane.add(button, 12, 12);
button.setOnAction(e ->{
    if(confirmDialog(
            "Sure you want to quit?",
            "Sure you want to quit?",
            "We're really closing - click yes to quit, no to stay in the app")
        ) {
        primaryStage.close();
    }

});

...

public boolean confirmDialog(String title, String headerText, String message) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, message, ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
        alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        alert.initOwner(scene); //scene must be accessible as a field
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(headerText);
        ButtonType result = alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.NO);
        return ButtonType.YES==result;
    }
```

Comment: Don't do something like this to get the value of a `Optional`. Use `orElse` instead. This way you avoid creating a container for the value to retrieve. (`AtomicBoolean` is especially bad since it also takes care of synchronizing the value.): `ButtonType result = alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.NO);`

Comment: Thanks @fabian, edited.